# Assign value from one array as a key to another array using lodash javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have 2 arrays -

**1-**  `Numbers = [3,4,5]` 
  **2-**  `selection= [ [1,2,3,4],[6,5,4,3],[2,9,4]]`

Now in output I want 3 should be key i.e index  of `[1,2,3,4]`  and so on

Output should be below  -

```
  selection= = { '3':[1,2,3,4] ,'4':[6,5,4,3] ,'5':[2,9,4]}
```

Comment: Iterate, get elements at current index from both arrays, add into object. Why you need lodash for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use _.zipObject https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#zipObject

```
_.zipObject(Numbers, selection)
```

Comment: This answer should clarify that it is using lodash. The only hint is the tag in the question, which is definitely not enough. Likewise, posting just a code snippet cannot possibly qualify as an "answer", even if it is technically correct.

Comment: Despite.. He got the most upvote here, because he is right and because he read the question AND the tag.
The answer can be found in lodash documentation, there is nothing to add I think.

Answer (score 3):

in plain Javascript, you could iterate `numbers` and build a new object with a number as key and take as value the item of `selection` with the same index.

```js
var numbers = [3, 4, 5],
    selection = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 5, 4, 3], [2, 9, 4]],
    result = {};

numbers.forEach(function (k, i) {
    result[k] = selection[i];
});

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var numbers = [3, 4, 5],
    selection = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 5, 4, 3], [2, 9, 4]],
    result = numbers.reduce((r, k, i) => Object.assign(r, { [k]: selection[i] }), {});

console.log(result);
```